# Split expressions but leave separators

Tags: c++, split

There are such expressions like:

```
name=="sometext"
value!=4
```

I would like to split such expressions with string separators like "==" and "!=" and keep these separators, so result would be:

```
name=="sometext"  ->  [name] [==] ["sometext"]
value!=4          ->  [value] [!=] [4]
```

How can it be done with Boost or some other library?

Comment: Are the expressions already a string, or are they like that in the code? And why, for what reason, do you want to split them?

Comment: This is a different question but the answer is the same for your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768948/extract-variables-from-string-math-expression/5769005#5769005

Comment: @Xeo: They are strings, not code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With boost I would use this simple regex :

```
(.*?)(==|!=)(.*)
```

Edit : **provided** that the expression is a string.

Edit 2 : explanation of the regex

```
// (.*?)(==|!=)(.*)
// 
// Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»
//    Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
//       Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
// Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(==|!=)»
//    Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «==»
//       Match the characters “==” literally «==»
//    Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «!=»
//       Match the characters “!=” literally «!=»
// Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3 «(.*)»
//    Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*»
//       Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
```