# How to convert characters '4/2.' to a number

Tags: fortran90

Is it possible to enter '4./2.' as character input, and then inside the program convert it to real number which the result is 2?

For example, while the program is executing I would write 4./2. at the screen prompt and then the program will write 2. on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you need to parse the input string yourself and evaluate the expression.

There are similar questions (with answers) for:

- [Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276021/evaluating-a-string-as-a-mathematical-expression-in-javascript)
- [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432245/java-parse-a-mathematical-expression-given-as-a-string-and-return-a-number)
- [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768948/extract-variables-from-string-math-expression)

though none of them has a direct "out of the box" working answer which will work for you without you writing you own equivalent code.